# Executable not searched in order of $PATH

Tags: bash, zsh, virtualenv

When I created a virtualenv for python it inserts a path at the front of `$PATH` so that I can run project-specific binaries. However when I need to run a program called `pip` instead of running from the first instance found in `$PATH` (The project directory) it runs from `/usr/bin` which appears later in `$PATH`.

But when I rename `pip` to `pip_old` in `/usr/bin/` it uses the binary in the project directory. So why does zsh prefer `/usr/bin` over the project directory even though it appears first in `$PATH`?

I use ZSH which is not only officially supported but also compatible with BASH. I also already tried to `rehash`

To be honest I am not even sure if this is the right Exchange to ask in so feel free to move it to a more appropriate place.

Comment: How did you set your path ? Probably the easiest solution is to name your "pip" program something more unique and put it in ~/bin

Comment: The path is set automagically by virtualenv. And pip is not my program. It is the package management system from Python.

Comment: Your $PATH is affected by the shell you are running and the way you configure the variable. If you can not tell us more then "The path is set automagically by virtualenv" then it is difficult to offer advice. Can you please be more specific and describe how you set your path?  I understand you are running zsh, is that correct ? Does it work as expected when you run bash ?????

Comment: @bodhi.zazen $PATH is normally modified by virtualenv. It _should_ add the project folder to the beginning of $PATH so that when I for example execute a python file with `python` it uses the binary provided by virtualenv to ensure consistency without affecting the system wide install of python. I checked that indeed the project's path is added to the beginning of $PATH.  I have checked with both zsh and bash and neither works. This should not be surprising since zsh is compatible with bash.  But if I rename the binary from the system install it uses the project directory's binary as expected.